# Ubuntu 20.04 cloud image can't get IP address

Tags: virtualization, ip, ubuntu-20.04, virsh, virt-install

When using `virt-install` to create a guest, CentOS 7.9 cloud image successfully gets an IP address, which can be checked with `sudo virsh domifaddr <domain>`. However, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS cloud image cannot, it just won't be assigned an IP address, no matter what I do. It successfully boots, and I can see the login prompt using `sudo virsh console <domain>`, but I can't ssh into it, since no IP is being assigned. I'm using virt-manager's default network. `sudo iptables -S` shows rules accepting in-going and on-going traffic for the DHCP ports on the host.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So that others can try to reproduce the problem, exactly which Ubuntu cloud image did you use?

Comment: I tried with both https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/focal-server-cloudimg-amd64.img and https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk-kvm.img.

Comment: I think that KVM image is broken. I can see on its serial console that it claims to have started the network, but it doesn't even attempt to do DHCP. It also fails to start sshd for reasons I don't know yet. And the QEMU guest agent isn't running. If I were an Ubuntu user I'd report these issues on Launchpad.

Comment: I would gladly do so. Could you please tell me how you confirmed that the mentioned services are not working (DHCP, sshd and QEMU guest agent)? Since there's no networking.

Comment: As I said, I looked at the serial console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using the `virt-resize` utility breaks Ubuntu cloud images somehow and it fails to start the DHCP service (needs confirmation). I stopped using `virt-resize` and started using only `qemu-img create` instead and providing the size parameter, and now DHCP works as expected and the virtual machine is assigned an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Not only virt-resize but also virt-customize and virt-sysprep, apparently.
It seems there is a better compatibility of virt-* with RHEL family (centos, fedora, rhel) - RedHat being the company owning KVM, that might be understable -
When using Ubuntu, better stick with cloud-init. after setting up stuff with cloud-init, you can still use libvirt suite to manage the VM.

OpenBSD ssh server may fail to start if you used virt-* for the customization of an ubuntu cloud image because tehre is a missing host ssh key.
You can fix that by running ssh-keygen -A within the guest OS (either through virt-customize or cloud-init)